# Arch Linux problem: What is causing the black screen problem when logging into Cinnamon?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, login, desktop-environment, cinnamon

I first posted this in February, but I'm making the problem clearer because I had no responses in 6 months, and the problem still exists.

My Arch boots to the terminal. I login as root.  I start Cinnamon and everything is fine.  I logout of root while in Cinnamon, and I'm returned to the terminal.  I login then under my own user account.  I start cinnamon and I get a black screen with a mouse pointer that I can move.  I can't get out of this and it requires a shutdown.  This problem is reproducable.

After booting up again, I login under my normal user account and it works, but the wallpaper has changed to some basic, default image.

What is happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: Post the relevant part of your Xorg log for the broken user session ...